# Tell Banshee to add covers inside MP3 tags

Tags: 12.04, banshee, mp3

I am using Banshee to encode my old CDs into nice MP3. Banshee is able to find CDs information and albums covers but it doesn't add these covers INSIDE the MP3's tag. As a consequence, when using another player, covers are not there.

Is there a way to change this behaviour without using an external MPE tags editor ?

Thanks,
Manu

Comment: This question is asking specifically about adding the cover art to the ID3 tags, which isn't currently possible with Banshee.

Answer (score 5):

Banshee doesn't currently have the option to save album art to a track's metadata. For more information, you can subscribe to [Bug 600885](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=600885).

Instead, Banshee stores art in `~/.cache/media-art` according to the [Media Art Storage Spec](https://live.gnome.org/MediaArtStorageSpec). Theoretically, if other media players followed the same specification, they would also have access to the same album art, but as far as I know, Banshee is the only media player that has implemented support for this spec.

Instead, you may wish to use one of Banshee's Community Extensions, [banshee-extension-albumartwriter](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/banshee-extension-albumartwriter/), which allows you to save the album art as a `cover.jpg` file inside the folder containing the audio file. This isn't quite what you're asking for, but it's much more widely supported by other music players, and it has the benefit of not duplicating the image file inside each individual track.

If this solution doesn't meet your needs, your only option may be to use another tool to do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The extension you mentionned, should at least avoid me to manually download the file from the web before using EasyTag for example to edit the tags. When does the copy takes place ? At import time only ? I'll also follow the bug 600885 and read all the comments to understand why it's not already done.

Comment: I tried the extension, enable it in the preferences but I don't have any cover.jpg file created. Do you have an idea on how enable this feature, what's wrong ?

Comment: @ManuelSelva, it copies covers from cache on Banshee startup.