# How get banshee-extension-albumartwriter working?

Tags: 12.04, banshee, mp3

In a previous question here: [Tell Banshee to add covers inside MP3 tags](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175231/tell-banshee-to-add-covers-inside-mp3-tags) someone told me about the banshee-extension-albumartwriter extension. 
I am very interested in this extension, but unfortunately I am not able to get it working. Moreover, i want to knowwhen the extension process to the copy ? At file import time, sometimes in a loop every X minutes it checks for all albums, over ?

I installed it from here **https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/banshee-extension-albumartwriter/**, I now see it in my banshee preferences, but even after enabling it through the checkbox I am not able to get cover.jpg files in my music directories.

I am running Banshee: *Banshee 2.4.1 (2.4.1) http://banshee.fm* according to banshee -version.

Any suggestions, ideas are welcome.

Thanks
Manu

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

> sudo apt-get remove banshee-extension-albumartwriter

This will first remove the extension ie. banshee-extension-albumartwriter

> sudo apt-get udpdate -fmy

This will update the repositories of your computer. For details of argument type "apt-get update -h"

> sudo apt-get upgrade -fmy

This will download and install the upgrades in your computer.For details of argument type "apt-get update -h"

> sudo apt-get install banshee-extension-albumwriter

This will download and install the banshee-extension-albumart-writer.

Comment: ... apart from the obvious typo - perhaps you can explain further what the "code" actually does.  Thanks.

Comment: I already did that and it didn't solve the issue.