# Where does banshee store id3 tags

Tags: 14.04, banshee, id3

I would like to know if there is a way that I can save all my album art in banshee in a folder,I'm very particular about the look and feel of my media player

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question in your title, [ID3 tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) are specific to mp3 files, and this metadata is stored in the files themselves. There are several [dedicated tag editors that work in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/297216/2079).

However, if you're specifically interested in album art, things are a bit different.  Banshee [does not have the option to embed album art into the files](https://askubuntu.com/a/175246/2079) themselves. Instead, Banshee saves album art in `~/cache/media-art`, according to the [Media Art Storage Spec](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/DraftSpecs/MediaArtStorageSpec).

It would be helpful to know what exactly you're trying to do, though. Generally the easiest way to organize covers in your media player is simply to edit the track in question and drag-and-drop your preferred album artwork onto the editor, replacing any existing cover.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to embed art directly into the id3 tag, you can use [EasyTAG](http://easytag.sourceforge.net).

Installation is pretty easy. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to open up a terminal and then enter the following:

`sudo apt-get install easytag`